# Unable to return any k8s client-go objects

Tags: go, kubernetes, client-go

I have to following code:

package analyzer

```
import (
    "context"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"

    "k8s.io/api/apps/v1beta1"
    metav1 "k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/apis/meta/v1"

    "k8s.io/client-go/kubernetes"
    _ "k8s.io/client-go/plugin/pkg/client/auth/gcp"
    "k8s.io/client-go/tools/clientcmd"
)

func getClientSetFromConfig() (*kubernetes.Clientset, error) {
    kubeconfig := filepath.Join(os.Getenv("HOME"), ".kube/config")
    config, err := clientcmd.BuildConfigFromFlags("", kubeconfig)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    return kubernetes.NewForConfig(config)
}

func GetDeploys() []v1beta1.Deployment {
    clientset, err := getClientSetFromConfig()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    deploys, err := clientset.ExtensionsV1beta1().Deployments("").List(context.Background(), metav1.ListOptions{})
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    return deploys.Items
}
```

I get the following error:

```
cannot use deploys.Items (variable of type []v1beta1.Deployment) as []v1beta1.Deployment value in return statement
```

which doesn't seem to make sense. I've tried to instead return `v1beta1.DeploymentList` directly itself but I get the same error. I've not encountered this ever before in Golang.

This kind of pattern seems to be deliberate in `k8s.io/client-go`.

- What's rationale behind this?
- What's the idiomatic way of writing functions like this?
- What feature/pattern of golang allows one to write functions like this that others can call and inspect the returned objects but cannot return them further?

Also, attaching the `go.mod` file for reference

```
module upgrades

go 1.14

require (
    github.com/fsnotify/fsnotify v1.4.9 // indirect
    github.com/imdario/mergo v0.3.9 // indirect
    github.com/mitchellh/go-homedir v1.1.0
    github.com/mitchellh/mapstructure v1.3.2 // indirect
    github.com/pelletier/go-toml v1.8.0 // indirect
    github.com/spf13/afero v1.2.2 // indirect
    github.com/spf13/cast v1.3.1 // indirect
    github.com/spf13/cobra v1.0.0
    github.com/spf13/jwalterweatherman v1.1.0 // indirect
    github.com/spf13/pflag v1.0.5 // indirect
    github.com/spf13/viper v1.7.0
    github.com/tealeg/xlsx v1.0.5
    golang.org/x/sys v0.0.0-20200610111108-226ff32320da // indirect
    gopkg.in/ini.v1 v1.57.0 // indirect
    k8s.io/api v0.18.3
    k8s.io/apimachinery v0.18.3
    k8s.io/client-go v0.18.3
    k8s.io/utils v0.0.0-20200603063816-c1c6865ac451 // indirect
)
```

Comment: You must show all your import statements and all relevant code. Most likely two packages use different versions (did you vendor some stuff?).

Comment: @Volker I don't think this is a related to different package versions, I can see all 3 of `k8s.io/api`, `k8s.io/apimachinery` and `k8s.io/client-go` are on `v0.18.3`. Also if I just print the deployments instead of returning it, It just works fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are returning the same type as declared But it is throwing an error,  `cannot use deploys.Items (variable of type []v1beta1.Deployment) as []v1beta1.Deployment value in the return statement.`

because you have imported the *wrong package*(`"k8s.io/api/apps/v1beta1"`) corresponding to the deployment **apiGroup extensions/v1beta1**.

1. if you are importing package `"k8s.io/api/apps/v1beta1"` then you should fetch deployment in the following way:

   `deployments, _ := clientset.AppsV1beta1().Deployments("").List(metav1.ListOptions{})`
2. if you are importing package `"k8s.io/api/extensions/v1beta1"` then you may list deployment like:

`deployments, _:=clientset.ExtensionsV1beta1().Deployments("").List(metav1.ListOptions{})`

Answer (score 1):

So the problem lied with wrong imports.

Basically `Deployments` are defined in `apps/v1beta2`. What I was doing was importing `"k8s.io/api/apps/v1beta1"`. I needed to change it to `"k8s.io/api/apps/v1beta2"`

Also for fetching that I needed to refer to `clientset.AppsV1beta2()` instead of `clientset.ExtensionsV1beta1()`